# Using cuda::morphologyex in opencv 3

Tags: opencv, cuda

I am working in an opencv project which usese the morphologyex function. Now I am trying to do it with gpu support.

When I compile my program with opencv 3.0 and cuda 7.5 support, it accepts most of the functions (such as cuda::threshold, cuda::cvtcolor,etc) except for morphologyEx. Note that morphologyex is called in opencv 2.4.9 as gpu::morphologyEx.

How can I use this function in OpenCV 3.0 or 3.1? If it isn't supported, is there an alternative to this function?

Actually I am using this function for background detection in nonuniform illumination. I am adding the code to the question. Please suggest me how can I replace the morphologyEx function.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{   
// Step 1: Read Image
Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

// Step 2: Use Morphological Opening to Estimate the Background
Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(15,15));
Mat1b background;
morphologyEx(img, background, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

// Step 3: Subtract the Background Image from the Original Image
Mat1b img2;
absdiff(img, background, img2);

// Step 4: Increase the Image Contrast
// Don't needed it here, the equivalent would be  cv::equalizeHist

// Step 5(1): Threshold the Image
Mat1b bw;
threshold(img2, bw, 50, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

// Step 6: Identify Objects in the Image
vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours(bw.clone(), contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


for(int i=0; i<contours.size(); ++i)
{
    // Step 5(2): bwareaopen
    if(contours[i].size() > 50)
    {
        // Step 7: Examine One Object
        Mat1b object(bw.size(), uchar(0));
        drawContours(object, contours, i, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

        imshow("Single Object", object);
        waitKey();
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

==========================================================================
Thanks to @Roy Falk
After reading the valuable comments and documentation, I felt that  morphologyEX function

```
morphologyEx(img, background, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
```

can be replaced by

```
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::Filter>morph = cuda::createMorphologyFilter(MORPH_OPEN, out.type(), kernel);
    morph->apply(out, bc);
```

feel free to say if I'm wrong

Comment: This seems a question more suitable for google. I'm assuming good faith here and that openCSV+cuda7.5 somehow complicates this, but you should invest a little more time in explaining why this is difficult to find on google. Setting up a scenario with an error message and architecture would go a long way toward generating good will and attracting people to this question. For example: I'm trying to run OpenCSV on a legacy embedded system running... It's only available with Cuda7.5 (obsolete) and code examples don't work because... I think I need a specific header file which isn't there...

Comment: Now the question is edited, Thanks

Comment: morphologyex seems to be missing from http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cudafilters/doc/filtering.html. Can you post the exact morpholyex invocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comment above, morphologyex is not in the 3.1 API.

I'm guessing you need to map the invocation as documented in [2.4 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f) to the way it's done in [3.1](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/cudafilters/doc/filtering.html).

Specifically, morphologyex has the following Parameters:

- src  Source image. **Use cuda::Filter and cuda::Filter::apply**
- dst  Destination image **same as above**
- op   Type of a morphological operation. **Try cuda::createMorphologyFilter**

...etc.

In other words, 2.4 did the operation in one go (morphologyex). In 3.1 you first create a filter using createFooFilter and then call apply filter.

Not really a definitive answer but more of a suggestion, but couldn't really write all this in a comment. Good luck.

=================================================================

**Edit:** Try looking at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/gpu/morphology.cpp. It shows how to use cuda::createMorphologyFilter

Comment: Firstly thanks for your quick reply. and sorry for my lack of knowledge in opencv.

Comment: I added the code to the question for a better understanding about the situation